# How to install self generated Certificate into Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I have created a  Self Signed Certificate Using  a Keytool , issuing this below  command under the bin directory

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

As a result this has produced a filename called as keystore.jks under the C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin   directory .

Could anybody please tell me how can i use this file , keystore.jks to test my Web Application which is running under the 
TOmcat 6.0 server .

I have only these things under the Tomcat bin directory

Please see the screen shot here

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=t62mht&s=7

I am completely new to this , please tell me if this approach is correct or not ??

Answer (score 0):

The official Tomcat documentation has a complete [chapter on setting up SSL with certificates for HTTPS](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html). I suggest going through that chapter one by one and follow the steps.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link , as mentioned i in the link i executed

keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA

and this produced a .keystore file inside my Users Directory inside windows

After executing this , I was  confused with this section 
Installing a Certificate from a Certificate Authority

It has asked to execute , this below command

keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA \
    -keystore

I have two questions with respect to the above

1. From where path( That is from jdk bin / tomcat bin ) i need to execute this above command
2. What should be the filename should be passed into "your_keystore_filename" section ??
3. And once we obtain a certreq.csr file , is it mantadatory to import an 
   Chain Certificate or Root Certificate into your keystore.